# Combining `tikzpicture` and `lstlisting`

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings, environments, framed

I'm working on a custom `lstlisting` environment, in which I use TikZ to add a frame and a title. Because of the widespread curly braces of `node` I cannot use `newenvironment`, so I have to resort to `NewEnviron`.

From the MWE and the picture below it should be clear what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{breaklines=true, postbreak={\mbox{$\hookrightarrow\space$}}, language=Mathematica}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations}

\tikzstyle{boxround} = [draw=black, thick, rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{head} =[draw=black, fill=white, thick, rectangle]

\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{code}{%
\bigskip
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [boxround] (box){%
\begin{minipage}{.94\textwidth}
\BODY
\end{minipage}};
\node[head, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {\textbf{Code listing}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\bigskip
}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}
How to get some \textsc{Mathematica} code (shown below) in this box...
\end{code}

\footnotesize
\begin{lstlisting}
B11[x_, y_] = Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1}}];
Plot3D[B11[x, y], {x, -.5, 1.5}, {y, -.5, 1.5}, PlotRange -> Full]; 
\end{lstlisting}
\normalsize

\end{document}
```

Which results in

[image]

If it weren't for `tikzpicture`, I would just use `lstnewenvironment`. But considering the widespread curly braces of `node` I don't know how I could. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, isn't easier to use [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) for the purpose?

Comment: Or have a look at the package `tcolorbox` with the library `listings`.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I'm not familiar with that package, but if it is possible to create an environment with the exact same look as the one in my MWE, then that might be the answer.

Comment: Do you want to print the code with the size `footnotesize`?

Comment: Look at "example 5" in [`mdframed-example-tikz.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed-example-tikz.pdf)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Well, I'd like to print the code in a smaller size than the default size. The `footnotesize` is a lazy temporary solution :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here a suggestion with `mdframed`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,breaklines=true, postbreak={\mbox{$\hookrightarrow\space$}}, language=Mathematica}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{lstlisting}{%
 innertopmargin=5pt,
 middlelinewidth=1pt,
 outerlinewidth=9pt,outerlinecolor=white,
 innerleftmargin=10pt,
 innerrightmargin=10pt,
 leftmargin=-9pt,rightmargin=-9pt,
 skipabove=\topskip,
 skipbelow=\topskip,
 roundcorner=5pt,
 singleextra={\node[draw, fill=white,anchor=west, xshift=10pt+1pt,font=\bfseries] at (O|-P) {Code Listings};},
 firstextra={\node[draw, fill=white,anchor=west, xshift=10pt+1pt,font=\bfseries] at (O|-P) {Code Listings};}
}

\lstnewenvironment{code}{%
  \mdframed[style=lstlisting]%
}{\endmdframed}

\begin{document}
Text
\begin{code}
B11[x_, y_] = Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1}}];
Plot3D[B11[x, y], {x, -.5, 1.5}, {y, -.5, 1.5}, PlotRange -> Full]; 
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*Update*

In the example below you have a new environment named `code` which has one optional and one mandatory argument. The optional argument is passed to `\lstset` and the mandatory one is the title.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,breaklines=true, postbreak={\mbox{$\hookrightarrow\space$}}, language=Mathematica}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\makeatletter
\def\mdf@@codeheading{Code Listings}%new mdframed key:
\define@key{mdf}{title}{%
   \def\mdf@@codeheading{#1}
}

\mdfdefinestyle{lstlisting}{%
 innertopmargin=5pt,
 middlelinewidth=1pt,
 outerlinewidth=9pt,outerlinecolor=white,
 innerleftmargin=10pt,
 innerrightmargin=10pt,
 leftmargin=-9pt,rightmargin=-9pt,
 skipabove=\topskip,
 skipbelow=\topskip,
 roundcorner=5pt,
 singleextra={\node[draw, fill=white,anchor=west, xshift=10pt+1pt,font=\bfseries] at (O|-P) {\csname mdf@@codeheading\endcsname};},
 firstextra={\node[draw, fill=white,anchor=west, xshift=10pt+1pt,font=\bfseries] at (O|-P) {\csname mdf@@codeheading\endcsname};}
}

\lstnewenvironment{code}[2][]{%
  \lstset{#1}%
  \mdframed[style=lstlisting,title={#2}]%
}{\endmdframed}

\begin{document}
Text

\begin{code}{Mathematice Listings}
B11[x_, y_] = Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1}}];
Plot3D[B11[x, y], {x, -.5, 1.5}, {y, -.5, 1.5}, PlotRange -> Full]; 
\end{code}

Text

\begin{code}{Code Listings}
B11[x_, y_] = Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1}}];
Plot3D[B11[x, y], {x, -.5, 1.5}, {y, -.5, 1.5}, PlotRange -> Full]; 
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! So the `singleextra` and `firstextra` just use TikZ code. By the way, why do we need both? For this case it seems kind of redundant.

Comment: Hmm, then there must be something wrong with the `firstextra` command because I don't get a **Code Listings** label when the code has a page break. Is the (O|-P) part for the node correct?

Comment: Oh and one other thing — I'd like to use an argument to set the text of the node. For instance, `\begin{code}{\textsc{Matlab} listing}`. I'm currently studying the mdframed-TikZ example PDF, the anwer might be in there :).

Comment: @Ailurus: Indeed. I will fix it tomorrow.

Comment: @Ailurus: For the first issue (`firstextra`)  I forgot a comma after the line `singleextra`. Sorry

Comment: @Ailurus: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here a suggestion using `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newenvironment{code}{%
  \tcblisting{listing only,colback=white,enlarge top by=5.5mm,enhanced,%
     overlay={\node[draw,fill=white,xshift=10pt,right,font=\bfseries] at (frame.north west) {Code Listings};},%
     listing options={basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,breaklines=true,%
                      postbreak={\mbox{$\hookrightarrow\space$}},language=Mathematica},%
  }%
 }%
 {\endtcblisting}

\begin{document}
\begin{code}
B11[x_, y_] = Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1}}];
Plot3D[B11[x, y], {x, -.5, 1.5}, {y, -.5, 1.5}, PlotRange -> Full]; 
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good alternative, but for now I'll stick with the other solution.