# Title above left line

Tags: mdframed

I'm  trying to create a `mdframed` environment where

1. The title is repeated on every page (works fine with `repeatframetitle`)
2. the title is left aligned relative to the normal text and this implies that the left line should start below the title.

Can someone help me with 2? How do I remove the line? And how to get rid of the ugly `10.4pt`?

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}


\newmdenv
  [leftmargin=0pt,
  topline=false,rightline=false,
  frametitle={\hspace{-10.4pt}I want the title here and no line beside it},
  repeatframetitle=true,
  everyline=true
  ]{test}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]


\begin{test}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If `tcolorbox` is a valid option you can try with

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,hooks}

\tcbset{%
% Title boxes will be added with overlays
  mytitle/.code={%
    \ifstrempty{#1}{}{\pgfkeysalso{%
        top=\baselineskip,
        overlay unbroken and first app = {%
        \node[rectangle, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,  
              anchor=south west,font=\bfseries]
         at (frame.north west)%
        {\strut#1};},
        overlay middle and last app = {%
        \node[rectangle, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,  
              anchor=south west,font=\bfseries]
         at (frame.north west)%
        {\strut#1};},
       enlarge top by = \baselineskip,
       enlarge top at break by= 0mm,
    }}},
}

\newtcolorbox{test}[1]{
    breakable, enhanced,%
    frame hidden, interior hidden, segmentation hidden,
    boxsep=0mm, right=0mm, rightrule=0mm, % aligns text to the right
    overlay unbroken={\draw (frame.north west)|-(frame.south east);},
    overlay first={\draw (frame.north west)|-(frame.south east);},
    overlay middle={\draw (frame.north west)|-(frame.south east);},
    overlay last={\draw (frame.north west)|-(frame.south east);},
    mytitle={#1}
    }

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]


\begin{test}{I want the title here and no line beside}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: tcolorbox is an option, but I don't know if I dare to use a new package with 200 pages of documentations for this project ;-). I have a quite tight time line. Do you know how I can align the text on the right to the normal right margin? I tried boxsep=0mm, right=0mm but there is still a small offset. And do you have some experience about the stability of the breakable frames? I don't want to have to fight against lonely lines or titles.

Comment: Does adding `boxrule=0mm` or `rightrule=0mm` to your test helps? It looks better to me. I'm not an expert but `draft` skin draws and measures all box components. Add it after `breakable, enhanced` and see what happens.

Comment: Yes rightrule=0mm did the trick (together with boxrule=0mm and right=0mm).

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be to draw the lines manually using `mdframed`'s nodes `(O)` (lower left corner) and `(P)` (upper right corner) and place the title in a node above `(O |- P)` (upper left corner). (This works with `framemethod=tikz` only.)

It is then necessary to provide a suitable definition for `singleextra`, `firstextra`, `middleextra` and `secondextra`:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newcommand*\testtitle{I want the title here and no line beside it}
\tikzset{
  testtitle/.style={
    anchor = south west,
    font = \bfseries,
    inner xsep = 0pt, outer xsep = 0pt, % align the text really at the left
    outer ysep = .5ex,
    overlay % necessary to avoid http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114829/5049
  }
}
\mdfdefinestyle{test}{
  leftmargin = 0pt,
  skipabove = 5ex, % enough space for the title node to be placed
  hidealllines = true,
  singleextra={
    \draw (O |- P) node[testtitle] {\testtitle} -- (O) -- (P |- O) ;
  },
  firstextra={
    \draw (O |- P) node[testtitle] {\testtitle} -- (O);
  },
  middleextra={
    \draw (O |- P) node[testtitle] {\testtitle} -- (O);
  },
  secondextra={
    \draw (O |- P) node[testtitle] {\testtitle} -- (O) -- (P |- O);
  }
}

\newmdenv[style=test]{test}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{test}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't it work too if I would simply draw the line with a shift and use the normal frametitle: `([yshift=-1cm]O |- P)`? (Can't test now, must go to an appointment).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Probably. I forgot you can do this...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that won't solve the problem with the horizontal shift of the title, though...

Comment: but shouldn't is be possible to get the correct shift with the O-node too?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't think that the title created with the `frametitle` option is placed in the tikzpicture of the frame. And even if it is I don't know if there is easy access to its node...